# How to display image stored in SQL Server in a details view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, sql-server-2008, razor

I have a table: [Stock_tbl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyWo2.jpg)

My controller code:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    Stock_ImgEntities db = new Stock_ImgEntities();
    var a = db.Stock_tbl.Where(q => q.Item_id == id).FirstOrDefault();
    return View(a);
}
```

My view markup:

```
@model IEnumerable<Stock_With_Image.Models.Stock_tbl>

<h2>Details</h2>

<div>
    <h4>Stock_tbl</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        @Model.Item_id
    </dl>

    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        @Model.Stock
    </dl>

    @{ 
        var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Image);
        var imgsrc = string.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}", base64);
    }
        <img src='@imgsrc'/>
</div>
```

When I'm running this it shows broken image. I'm new to this framework and never tried to store image into DB any help.

Thank you

Comment: put the img tag inside the `@{}` block it should fix it without the `''`

Comment: @jamiedanq nothing happened same problem

Comment: try <img src="data:image/png;base64, ............

png instead of jpg